# C# Mapster error when trying to map IEnumerable<T> where T requires DI Service

Tags: c#, .net, mapster

I have the following class:

```
public class FooDto
{
    public string Secret { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured the mapping as follows:

`config.NewConfig<Foo, FooDto>() Map(dest => dest.Secret, src => MapContext.Current.GetService<IEncryptionService>().Decrypt(src.Secret));`

When I try to map to a list:
`_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FooDto>>(fooObjList);`

I Get the error  "Mapping must be called using ServiceAdapter"

However when I map without a list it works fine:
`_mapper.Map<FooDto>(fooObj);`

It seems that when mapping to a collection the MapContext is unavailable

Comment: What does this question have to do with AutoMapper?